# Remove the first and last char in the file

Tags: bash

I have a data file, and I want to remove the first and last char. Is there a simple way to do this? I searched online, but I didn't find a simple way.
Thanks!

Comment: It is always recommended to add your samples of input and output in your posts; along with your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem.

Comment: (untested; not reliable with utf-8 text): `head -c -1 file | tail -c +2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sed -i '1s/.\(.*\)/\1/; $s/\(.*\)./\1/' path/to/file.txt
```

`-i`: modify file in place

`1s`: apply substitute command to line number 1 only

`$s`: apply substitute command to last line only

`\( ... \)`: a capture group to make use of later by referencing it with `\1`

Basically these are two sed substitute commands glued with `;`

EDIT: Just realized you said simple... Not sure if this falls under simple.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, if you are ok with `awk`.

```
awk '
prev{
  if(++count==1){
      print substr(prev,2)
  }
  else{
      print prev
  }
  prev=""
}
{
  prev=$0
}
END{
  if(prev){
      print substr(prev,1,length(prev)-1)
  }
}'    Input_file
```

Comment: That trims every line, not the file as a whole.

Comment: @Shawn, aahhhh sorry I didn't get it correctly, let me fix it now. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk*. Testing with `Lorem\nipsum` (no trailing newline, as otherwise that would be removed**):

```
$ echo -en Lorem\\nipsum | awk -v RS="^$" '{gsub(/^.|.$/,"")}1'
orem
ipsu
```

Solution reads the whole input into memory before processing so that could be considered a downside.

* Succesfully tested with gawk, awk-20121220 and Busybox awk, failed with mawk.

** "Last character":

```
$ echo -e Lorem\\nipsum  # outputs:
Lorem\n
ipsum\n                  # \n is last char but print (well, 1) adds another
```

To avoid that, use `printf` instead:

```
$ echo -e Lorem\\nipsum | awk -v RS="^$" '{gsub(/^.|.$/,"");printf "%s",$0}'
orem
ipsum$
```